# How to solve "invalid operands to binary expression" in C++?

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector, std

I have a base `class` and a sub-`class` that inherits it. I have overridden the operators `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` in the base `class`, with the purpose of `std::sort`ing a `vector` with this class. When I `std::sort`, I do so by calling `std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end())`.

However, I keep getting the error `invalid operands to binary expression ('const my_sub_class' and 'const my_sub_class')`. I also get like 8 errors and a whole essay of sub-errors for every place I try to implement the sort. For example, I get `in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::greater<my_sub_class>::operator()' requested here, if (__comp(*--__last, *__first))`, which seems to be the various sub functions.

I hope I've just missed an include, but apart from `#include <vector>` (d'uh) and `#include <algorithm>` I can't figure out what else I need. I have tried the overloaded operators separately through `if`'s, and they work. The `vector<my_sub_class>` works as well. I've also tried various solutions such as overloading the operators in the sub-class, and supplying an explicit sort function (such as `greater<my_sub_class>`, own functions, reverse sort order via `rbegin()` and `rend()`), but nothing seems to work (although some of my solutions give different errors (too varied to include all here).

**EDIT:**

Here's some code that reproduces the error
Header File:

```
#ifndef H_DEBUGGING
#define H_DEBUGGING

class my_class {
  public:
    void set_value(int in_value);
    int get_value();
    bool operator < (const my_class & in_my_class);
    bool operator > (const my_class & in_my_class);
    // Some other stuff

  protected:
    int mValue;
    my_class();
    // Some other stuff
};

class my_sub_class: public my_class {
  public:
    my_sub_class();
    // Some other stuff
  protected:
    // Some other stuff
};

void debug_custom_class_vector();

#endif
```

Class File:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Debugging.hpp"

my_class::my_class() {
}

void my_class::set_value(int in_value) {
  mValue = in_value;
}

int my_class::get_value() {
  return mValue;
}

bool my_class::operator < (const my_class & in_my_class) {
  return mValue < in_my_class.mValue;
}

bool my_class::operator > (const my_class & in_my_class) {
  return mValue > in_my_class.mValue;
}

my_sub_class::my_sub_class() {
}

void debug_custom_class_vector() {
  my_sub_class sub_a, sub_b, sub_c;
  sub_a.set_value(2);
  sub_b.set_value(1);
  sub_c.set_value(3);

  std::vector<my_sub_class> my_custom_vector;
  my_custom_vector.push_back(sub_a);
  my_custom_vector.push_back(sub_b);
  my_custom_vector.push_back(sub_c);

  std::cout << "Unsorted: " << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << my_custom_vector[i].get_value() << std::endl;
  }

  // std::sort(my_custom_vector.begin(), my_custom_vector.end(), std::greater<my_sub_class>());

  std::cout << "Sorted: " << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << my_custom_vector[i].get_value() << std::endl;
  }
}

// Some other stuff
```

When I then run from my main, I get:

```
Unsorted: 
0: 2
1: 1
2: 3
Sorted: 
0: 2
1: 1
2: 3
```

and when I uncomment the `std::sort` line in the class file, I get the error.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Did you make those overloads `const` functions? Also, "*I hope I've just missed an include*" we really can't tell you without seeing a [MCVE] of your code.

Comment: Please post your code; otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: Please post the functions in question. That said, I have a hunch you need to change it to something like `operator<(const& class) const {` But please post the code so we don't have to guess, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` requires the operators to be `const` methods. Declaration

```
virtual bool operator < (classA a);
virtual bool operator < (const classA& a);
virtual bool operator < (classA& a) const;
```

All three declarations are not suitable for your case, either won't compile or won't work. You need:

```
virtual bool operator < (const classA& a) const;
```

Plus, you'll probably need to make copy/move operators virtual...

Also, to begin with, you shouldn't write virtual comparison operator (it cripples performance, possibly 10~100 times for sort). Better use lambda functions for customized sorting. Only in some really weird cases you have to resort to virtual functions. Honestly, I don't know why you need comparison operator to be virtual for sorting... I think you made an error somewhere.

So you'd better check out lambda functions in C++11 and redesign your code.